# Could not resolve view with name 'sport' in servlet with name 'SpringApp'

Tags: json, spring, jsp

I am using Spring with a JSP and jqGrid and trying to post JSON data to my server.

The GET successfully loads the JSP when I go to the URL:
`http://localhost:8080/sportsSpring/sport-management/sport/`

My POST successfully saves to the database but fails to reload the JSP afterwards with the exception "Could not resolve view with name 'sport' in servlet with name 'SpringApp'".

SpringApp-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="spring.controller"/>

<!-- To enable @RequestMapping process on type level and method level -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
            <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
                <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
                <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sportController" class="spring.controller.SportController">
    <property name="SportDao" ref="SportDao" />
</bean>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:jd="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd">
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="spring.controller,spring.beans"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>

<bean id="SportDao" class="spring.controller.SportDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sport-management/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tags/c.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

My SportController:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/sport")
public ModelAndView getSportList() throws NumberFormatException, SQLException, JSONException
{
    sportDao = getSportDao();   
    List<SportBean> sportBeanList = sportDao.getSports();
    JSONArray sportJsonArray = convertToJson(sportBeanList);

    return new ModelAndView("sport", "sports", sportJsonArray);
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", value="/sport")
public ModelAndView addSport(@RequestBody String body) throws SQLException, JSONException
{
    SportBean sportBean = convertToBean(body, true);

    sportDao = getSportDao();
    sportDao.saveSport(sportBean);

    return new ModelAndView("sport");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: Can we see your full context configuration?

Comment: Why do you have `produces = "application/json"` if what you want to do is forward to a JSP generating, I guess, HTML? Try removing this attribute.

Comment: @JBNizet The `produces` is just used to map to an `Accept` header. It has no bearing on the generated response.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I doubt this is the issue indeed, but the doc also says: "use of the produces condition ensures the actual content type used to generate the response respects the media types specified in the produces condition". Likewise, the `@ResponseBody` annotation on the other method doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @JBNizet Even though there is a `@ResponseBody`. Spring will use a `ModelAndViewMethodReturnValueHandler` to render the body, which is equivalent to the method not having the annotation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I have added the full code for my servlet.xml, applicationContext.xml and web.xml.

Comment: @JBNizet: I have changed the produces to consumes. I have the consumes annotation because I receive JSON data from a jqGrid I am using. I have removed the `@ResponseBody` annotation from the GET method.

Comment: Is there a file `/sports.jsp` directly in the `Web Content` or `webapp` folder?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: My sports.jsp is at the same level as my WEB-INF folder. My JSP is at apache-tomcat/webapps/sportsSpring/sport.jsp and my classes are in apache-tomcat/webapps/sportsSpring/WEB-INF/classes. My XML files are in apache-tomcat/webapps/sportsSpring/WEB-INF

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem. Can you review all configs and review what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

- remove this:`<property name="prefix" value="/"/>`
- or try to see what is actually the prefix to your path such as WEB-INF folder for your JSP pages such as     `<property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/views/"/>`

Comment: The default `prefix` value for a `UrlBasedViewResolver` is `""`. Removing the `<property>` won't change anything because the path will be relative to the servlet context root anyway. Also, your second point wouldn't explain why the GET request can successfully render the jsp.